# Why does the last "else" not restart the recursion with the new values?

Tags: if-statement, recursion, ocaml

So im learning Ocaml at University and this year the code we create have some special rules : no loops or arrays(i dont know why but she almost seemed angry when a friend of mine used them at the exam so) so we must handle the problems with only recursion and here i must create a code to return all twin prime numbers such as 3,5 5,7 or 11,13 that are between (0,2) and (n,n+2) so i tried to do it this way :

```
let rec calculpj p q n =
  if q = p + 2 && n > 0 then  
    begin
      if q mod p != 0 && p mod q != 0 then 
        begin 
          print_int(p) ; 
          print_int(q) 
        end
      else 
        calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1) 
    end
  else 
    calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1) ;;
      
calculpj 3 5 3
```

but for a reason i cant understand why the last "else" dont restart the recursion with the new values since the first "loop" return the value as intented.
And if anyone want to know where this exercice come from it is from an exam where the teacher didnt gave us the answers so i dont have anything to correct myself.

I tried a lot of things but since im new to Ocaml i dont know how to find what cause my problem.

Comment: Try to avoid unnecessary `begin ... end` or parens. The outermost set in your code are extraneous.

Comment: Note that you can remove the `begin ... end` entirely in your code by printing with something like  `Format.printf "%d %d\n" p q` which is a single expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several cases. One of them is this:

```
begin 
print_int(p) ; 
print_int(q)
end
```

This covers the case where the two `mod` values aren't 0. Note that this case stops here. There is nothing to do after printing the two ints. This is why your code stops after the first time. The two recursive calls to `calculpj` are for other cases.

Other observations:

The usual not-equal operator in OCaml is `<>`. You're using one that should be avoided until later in your studies :-)

You test whether n > 0, which makes sense. But when it's false you're calling `calculpj` recursively anyway. This suggests that if you fix your first problem you'll have an infinite loop instead.

It's not clear why you're testing whether `q = p + 2`. If you supply two values that differ by 2, then your recursive calls will cause them to always differ by 2.

Comment: Thanks for this i tried to change a bit my code to match what i really want and can you explain to me what are the differences between the <> and =! not-equal operator ? if you have any idea

Comment: `<>` is "not equal to" whereas `=!` checks if physical memory addresses are different, and to complicate it a tad more `!=` checks if 2 values do not refer to the same physical memory location. **So** use `<>` for **not equal to**

Answer (score 1):

A number is prime if it has exactly two distinct positive divisors: 1 and the number itself. So, create a function that uses those characteristics to test if it is prime:

```
## pseudo code
Function is_prime(n)
  Function check(i)
    If i * i > n Then
      Return true
    Else If n mod i = 0 Then
      Return false
    Else
      Call check(i + 1)
  End Function
  If n > 1 and check(2) Then
    Return true
  Else
    Return false
End Function
```

So now the main game is to repeat through numbers via recursion so you need a definite way to break out. I suggest you simply ask for a number of pairs, and once that is reached the recusion will end. Below parameter `n` decreases by 1 for each pair that is found and exits when it reaches 0. The second parameter `start`  simply allows you to nominate the starting point e.g. 1

```
## pseudo code
Function twin_primes(n, start)
  Function helper(p, q, n, result)
    If n equals 0 Then
      Return result
    Else If p and q are twin primes Then
      Decrease n by 1
      Add (p, q) to result
      Call helper(p + 1, q + 1, n, result)
    Else
      Call helper(p + 1, q + 1, n, result)
  End Function
  Call helper(start, start + 2, n, empty list)
End Function
```

this is about as far as I can go.

Comment: I understand what you mean about a function that can test if a number is prime and currently trying to create a new function that will return a boolean and try to pass it as an argument into the if q mod p != 0 && p mod q != 0 instead of doing q mod p != 0 i expect to just call the function in it to return true or false if the number is prime thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your specific code, let's simplify it by removing some of the noise:

```
let rec calculpj p q n =
  if q = p + 2 && n > 0 then  
    if q mod p != 0 && p mod q != 0 then 
        Format.printf "%d %d\n" p q
      else 
        calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1)
  else 
    calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1)
```

Now, we know that `p` and `q` always get incremented by the same amount, so let's remove that check that they differ by two.

```
let rec calculpj p q n =
  if n > 0 then  
    if q mod p != 0 && p mod q != 0 then 
        Format.printf "%d %d\n" p q
      else 
        calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1)
  else 
    calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1)
```

And then we can eliminate some levels of nesting.

```
let rec calculpj p q n =
  if n > 0 && q mod p != 0 && p mod q != 0 then 
    Format.printf "%d %d\n" p q
  else if n > 0 then
    calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1)
  else 
    calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1)
```

Note that the last two outcomes are the same, so we can reduce this further.

```
let rec calculpj p q n =
  if n > 0 && q mod p != 0 && p mod q != 0 then 
    Format.printf "%d %d\n" p q
  else
    calculpj (p + 1) (q + 1) (n - 1)
```

So, when you call `calculpj p q n`, `n` is greater than `0` *and* `q mod p` does not equal `0` *and* `p mod q` does not equal `0`, so `p` and `q` get printed. There's no recursive call, so nothing further happens.

Aside from this, your logic will not correctly identify primes.

For recursion to work, you need a base case that will terminate the recursion. In your case, if `n` is equal or less than zero, the function's work is done.

```
let calculpj p q n =
  if n <= 0 then ...
```

You need to identify a case where `p` and `q` are both prime.

```
let calculpj p q n =
  if n <= 0 then ...
  else if is_prime p && is_prime q then ...
```

And you need to handle the case where they *aren't.*

```
let calculpj p q n =
  if n <= 0 then ...
  else if is_prime p && is_prime q then ...
  else ...
```

In both of the latter cases you need to update the state. Both `p` and `q` will be incremented, but `n` should only be decremented if you've found a matching pair of numbers.

### Alternatives

Having addressed that, I encourage you to think about the end goal. You need numbers starting at a certain number, separated by a certain step, and you need a certain number of them. This does not necessarily match your function signature, but the approach can be adapted.

The key to programming is breaking complex programs down. OCaml in my experience makes this very straightforward. We can start with a sequence of integers from our start number. This is lazy. We can go as far through this [sequence](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) as we need to.

Our next step is to map a number like `3` in our sequence to a tuple like `(3, 5)`. We then filter out only tuples where both elements are prime. For this you'll need to define `is_prime`, likely using a very basic method of checking factors.

```
let is_prime n =
  let rec check pf =
    if pf = n then ...
    else if n mod pf = 0 then ...
    else ...
  in
  if n = 0 || n = 1 then false
  else check 2
```

Once you have filtered your sequence down to only pairs of integers separated by a step number, you just need to limit your sequence to a certain number of elements, then consume the sequence by converting to a list.

```
# let calc start step take = 
    start 
    |> Seq.ints 
    |> Seq.map (fun i -> (i, i + step)) 
    |> Seq.filter (fun (a, b) -> is_prime a && is_prime b) 
    |> Seq.take take 
    |> List.of_seq;;
val calc : int -> int -> int -> (int * int) list = <fun>
# calc 3 2 3;;
- : (int * int) list = [(3, 5); (5, 7); (11, 13)]
```

Or we could just print it.

```
# let calc start step take =
    start
    |> Seq.ints
    |> Seq.map (fun i -> (i, i + step))
    |> Seq.filter (fun (a, b) -> is_prime a && is_prime b)
    |> Seq.take take
    |> Seq.iter (fun (a, b) -> Format.printf "%2d, %2d\n" a b);;
val calc : int -> int -> int -> unit = <fun>
# calc 3 2 3;;
 3,  5
 5,  7
11, 13
- : unit = ()
# calc 1007 2 3;;
1019, 1021
1031, 1033
1049, 1051
- : unit = ()
```